# VS2013 a project does not load and VS freezes

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2013 Professional edition on Windows 10.

I have a project called "Asset" that contains a folder called images that contains tens of image files.

One day I accidentally pressed on "**Show all files**" button at the top of the solution explorer, and VS attempted to load (or showing) all those image files, and it was taking too much time, so I killed VS in the middle o that process.

When I reopen the solution, it loads all the other projects in the solution except for this "Asset" project, and VS just freezes.

This issue does not happen to the other developers in my team, so I'm assuming I messed up some settings on my computer

I tried the following but none of them worked:

- Removed suo file.
- Disable Resharper
- Uninstalled TypeScript 1.6 extension
- Repair VS2013
- Uninstalled VS2013 and reinstalled using Web installer

I am not sure what else I should do to fix the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the project in the Recent project list or in the projects folder. Otherwise create a new project and add all the files required.

Comment: It seems I messed up some info in the registry or whatever... and I wasn't able to find a way to do a complete "clean" installation of VS to delete all those things. I ended up simply re-creating the project as you suggest. Thanks for your help.